# $(a+b)(a+bc) + (b+c)(b+ca) + (c+a)(c+ab) \ge 12$ if $ab+bc+ca=3$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be real positive number, $ab+bc+ca=3$.
Prove that $$P=(a+b)(a+bc) + (b+c)(b+ca) + (c+a)(c+ab) \ge 12$$
My attempt: $$P=(a+b)(a+bc) + (b+c)(b+ca) + (c+a)(c+ab) \ge 3\sqrt[3]{(a+b)(a+bc)(b+c)(b+ca)(c+a)(c+ab)}$$
$$P \ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{8}{9}\cdot(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)(a+bc)(b+ca)(c+ab)}$$
$$P \ge3\sqrt[3]{\frac{8}{3}\cdot(a+b+c)(a+bc)(b+ca)(c+ab)} $$
I can't prove $(a+bc)(b+ca)(c+ab)\ge 8$
Could you help me ?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2237591p17138075

Comment: @LightYagami nice find but that solution is using a computer SOS solver,not by hand :(

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore: What is SOS solver?

Comment: @LightYagami Some inequality afficado's have a software that gets a Sum of squares  of a given inequality (I regret that i dont have ) They work sometimes but usually they give messy results like this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last inequlaity is equivalent to
$$
a^2b^2c^2+abc(a^2+b^2+c^2)+a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+abc\ge 8.
$$
Since
$$
a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)=(a+b+c)^2-6~\text{and}~
\\
a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2=(ab+bc+ca)^2-2abc(a+b+c)=9-2abc(a+b+c),
$$
the previous inequlaity is equivalent to
$$
a^2b^2c^2+abc(a+b+c)^2-6abc+9-2abc(a+b+c)+abc\ge 8,
$$
or
$$
a^2b^2c^2+abc((a+b+c)^2-2(a+b+c))+1\ge 5abc.
$$
Now note that $(a+b+c)^2\ge 3(ab+bc+ca)=9$, so $a+b+c\ge 3$ and hence,
$$
(a+b+c)^2-2(a+b+c)=(a+b+c-1)^2-1\ge 3.
$$
Thus, it's sufficient to prove that
$$
a^2b^2c^2+3abc+1\ge 5abc\Leftrightarrow (abc-1)^2\ge 0,
$$
which is true.

Comment: Oh thank you bro @richrow

Answer (score 1):

Hints :

We have :

$$P=(a+b)(b+bc) + (b+c)(c+ca) + (c+a)(a+ab) \ge 12$$

Using :$$(a-b)(a+b)+(b-c)(b+c)+(c-a)(c+a)=0$$

Now we use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to get :

$$P\geq \sum_{cyc}^{}(a+\sqrt{abc})^{2}\geq 12$$

Now expand and use the substitution $3u=a+b+c$,$3v^2=ab+bc+ca$ and $w^3=abc$

Conclude using uvw's method .